# decoupling app and libraries in CMake project

Tags: c++, cmake

I had a project that was configured to be:

CMake Project

- static Lib A src (depends on B)

  - static Lib B src (depends on Qt)
- App src (statically links with LibA)

Each of these folders had its own CMakeLists.txt but all were part of the same CMake project.  Things were working fine.

Then for the purpose of more easily separating the library source and the app source into different source code repositories, I started to learn about the creation of CMake packages and performing find_package on LibA.  I rearranged things so that now the libraries are their own CMake project, which requires I run "cmake --build . --target install" to put the packages in a common area (not in the build folder).

The app similarly became its own CMake package, and I *thought* I would only need to find_package(LibA).  It turned out I also needed to find_package on LibB because there was one header that the App needed.  But the unexpected part is that the App needed to find_package on Qt5Widgets, Qt5Core, and Qt5Gui just as LibB did.  That's the part that I don't quite understand.  When everything was one giant project, the App's CMakeLists.txt only needed to link against LibA.  Was all of the other stuff just taken care of without me knowing?  Am I naive to think that performing find_package on LibA and LibB would somehow cause the Qt libs to be linked in to the App as well?

This might be a lousy question, because I have things working again.  I just want to make sure I understand the why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using static libraries in C++ does not pull in their dependencies, so they have to be specified explicitly while linking the executable (as compared to dynamic ones).

A [static library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29#Static_libraries) is essentially a pre-compiled archive of functions (an object file), which get linked into your applications by your C++ linker in a similar way as any other object file would. As such, it does not include information about its dependencies.

A [shared (dynamic) library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29#Shared_libraries) is a more complex (and generic) thing, allowing to load and link code run-time. This is done by a [dynamic linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker), which will also bring it any dependencies of the loaded library recursively.

For this reason, if you want to avoid specifying the dependencies explicitly, a dynamic library might be a better choice (it might be a better choice for a variety of other reasons as well :) ).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  It does seem to me that CMake makes things easier than it otherwise would be when linking statically within one monolithic project, which caused the confusion on my part when separating into two projects.  That's not necessarily bad, I just needed to know it was doing that on my behalf.